# MUI data-grid-pro Expand cell renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, popper

I'm trying to use the [Expand cell renderer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Can.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Can.png): https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#RenderExpandCellGrid.js provided in the documentation while using data-grid-pro. It started to behave strangely after I added pinned columns:

```js
      <DataGridPro
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pinnedColumns: { left: ["col2"], right: [] },
        }}
      />
```

1. For pinned columns, the popper is displayed bellow the cell:[cut-off popper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Can.png)
2. When I move over cells, all the lines I moved over stays selected: [3 selected rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpv84.png)

I'm looking for a solution to implement both column pinning and Expand cell renderer

Answer (score 0):

did you try to modify the `z-index` of the proper such that it appears on top of the pinned column?